# How do I create a dog's age calculator HTML form with my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I new to javascript and I was wondering how I turn my javascript code into a HTML form. The idea is that I'm using [this website about your dog's age](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/how-to-calculate-your-dogs-age) and making something more interactive, like a calculator.

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

The HTML I have so far is:

```
<form action="">
 <h4>Size</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" checked>Small<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large">Large<br>

  <h4>Age</h4>
  <p>Type in an age between 1 and 16.</p>
  <input type="number" name="age" min="1" max="16"><br><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the javascript is something like this (it's not perfect but it works), and only prints to the console. I want it to print to the user instead when they press the submit button.

```
var dogSize = "medium"; // small, medium, or large?
var dogAge = 13; // type in an age between 1-16

// BASIC RULES
if (dogSize !== "small" && dogSize !== "medium" && dogSize !== "large") {
  console.log("ERROR: Please type in either small, medium, or large");
}
else if (dogAge < 1 || dogAge > 16) {
  console.log("ERROR: Type in an age between 1 and 16.");
}

// First 5 years
else if (dogAge === 1 && dogSize === "small") {
  console.log("Your dog is 15 in human years.");
}
else if (dogAge === 1 && dogSize === "medium") {
  console.log("Your dog is 15 in human years.");
}
else if (dogAge === 1 && dogSize === "large") {
  console.log("Your dog is 15 in human years.");
}

etc...
```

I have more code written, but the important thing is linking up the HTML buttons with the code.

I'd really appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using a bunch of if/else, you might want to look at deconstructing the calculator so that the dog ages can be calculated as a function of size and year (i.e. a formula that you can use).

Comment: [The `Document` method `querySelector()` returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specified `selector`, or group of selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty broad because there isn't just one thing that you need to do. Essentially, you need to do 3 things for each element that you want to connect to JavaScript:

1. You'll need to get a JavaScript reference to the element(s) that need to be
   hooked up to JavaScript and that can be done in a variety of ways
   (**[`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**, **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**, **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**,
   etc.)
2. You'll need to decide which events should trigger the event
   callbacks (`click`, `change`, `input`, `submit`, etc.).
3. Then you need to configure event handling callback functions for
   those found elements, which is done with **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

Before you embark on this solution, I strongly suggest you investigate working with the **[Document Object Model (DOM) API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)**, **[DOM Event Handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Events)** and specifically, **[form events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)**.

One other thing, if you intend for this to just be a calculator and not actually submit data anywhere, you shouldn't be using a `submit` button, you should just have a `button` button.

Here's a basic example:

```js
// Get a reference to the elements that we'll be working with:
let form = document.querySelector("form");  // Find the first <form> element in the document
let age = document.querySelector("input[name='age']"); // Find the first <input> with: name="age"

// Get all the <input> elements with name="size" and create an Array to store them in.
// .querySelectorAll() returns a list of the element nodes as a collection, but if
// we want to loop through that list using the .forEach() method for looping, we have
// to convert that list into a true JavaScript Array for the best compatibility across
// different browsers. Array.prototype.slice.call() takes the argument you pass to it
// and converts it into an Array.
let sizes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='size']"));

// Set up event handlers for the elements.
// Here, we have three ways to trigger the calculation...
//   1. As the user enters a number for age
//   2. As the user changes the size
//   3. When the user clicks the button

// Of course, you could have each element hooked up to different 
// functions if desired, but it doesn't seem like that is what you
// would want in this case.
age.addEventListener("input", calculate);
form.addEventListener("submit", calculate);

// We'll loop over all the radio buttons in the array
sizes.forEach(function(radioButton){
  // and set each one up with an event handler
  radioButton.addEventListener("click", calculate);
});

// These are the functions that were referenced above and that will be called 
// when the events that they are tied to occur. Obviously, add you own custom
// code inside of each:
function calculate(){
  console.log("...calculating...");
}
```

```html
<form>
 <h4>Size</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" checked>Small<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large">Large<br>

  <h4>Age</h4>
  <p>Type in an age between 1 and 16.</p>
  <input type="number" name="age" min="1" max="16"><br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: Start with suggestion No 2.  Add an OnClick handler to the Input button, I would change it from type "Submit" to type Button.  Regardless of details start there...

Comment: @akaphenom Uh no. You have to start with #1 because if you don't, you  won't have anything to set the event up on. And, don't use `on` anything (that's a 20+ year old antiquated technique that should not be used). Once you understand that `onXyz` event attributes should never be used, you'll understand why you have to start with #1.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. I think this is an easy way to accomplish that task.

You should perform an action after the submit event has been triggered. You can do something like:

```
form = document.getElementById("my-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", calculageAge, false);
```

You might also want to add an HTML element inside the form where the result will be displayed. Something like

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

In your calculateAge function, you should modify the DOM and display the result with

```
// You should set this variable in your if...else statements
calculatedAge = "The age of the dog";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = calculatedAge;
```

Comment: Please, please, please don't advocate inline HTML event attributes! This is a 20+ year old technique that was used before there were web standards and there are many important reasons not to use them. But, because they are so pervasive, people just copy that technique and perpetuate this very bad coding paradigm. Separate your JavaScript from your HTML and use the DOM API standard for configuring events.

Answer (score 0):

Add specific `id`s to your elements on html file. Also use right selectors to read the values

**document.getElementById(INP_ID)** : Get an element which its id equals to `INP_ID`

**document.getElementById(INP_ID).checked** Check the element with id INP_ID is checked or not

**document.getElementById(INP_ID).value;** Get the value of element.

```js
var dogSize = "medium"; // small, medium, or large?

if (document.getElementById("r1").checked) {
  dogSize = "small";
} else if (document.getElementById("r3").checked) {
  dogSize = "large"
}

var dogAge = document.getElementById("age").value; // type in an age between 1-16

// BASIC RULES
if (dogSize !== "small" && dogSize !== "medium" && dogSize !== "large") {
  console.log("ERROR: Please type in either small, medium, or large");
} else if (dogAge < 1 || dogAge > 16) {
  console.log("ERROR: Type in an age between 1 and 16.");
} else if (dogAge === 1 && dogSize === "small") {
  // First 5 years
  console.log("Your dog is 15 in human years.");
} else if (dogAge === 1 && dogSize === "medium") {
  console.log("Your dog is 15 in human years.");
} else if (dogAge === 1 && dogSize === "large") {
  console.log("Your dog is 15 in human years.");
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <h4>Size</h4>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="size" value="small" checked>Small<br>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="size" value="medium">Medium<br>
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="size" value="large">Large<br>

  <h4>Age</h4>
  <p>Type in an age between 1 and 16.</p>
  <input id="age" type="number" name="age" min="1" max="16"><br><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

**Update**

You can use these for selecting elements without adding any `id` or change your html code

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("size")
  console.log(radios)

  if (radios[0].checked) {
    dogSize = "small";
  } else if (radios[2].checked) {
    dogSize = "large";
  }

  var dogAge = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value; // type in an age between 1-16
```

Comment: While adding `id`s to elements certainly *can* work, defaulting to that as a way of getting all your DOM references will create a very brittle solution. CSS classes, or querying based on position in the DOM or by attribute value are much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, yes, you've expanded your answer and that's good, but you should know and point out that `.getElementsByName()` (along with `.getElementsByTagName()`, and `.getElementsByClassName()`) return "live" node lists, which hurt performance and so should only be used in cases where that is necessary. `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` really should be used in most cases.

Comment: Not dynamic elements added?! even if we use them in a function after adding new elements?? Where I can find these performance issues? @ScottMarcus

Comment: The way a live node list works is that is scans the document for matching elements ***every time*** the variable that holds the reference to the node list is used. That's the only way it can correctly reference all the current elements that match the query. So, if you have just one live node list, but refer to it 3 times in your code, the DOM will be completely scanned 3 times.

Comment: When elements will not be dynamically added/removed from the DOM, live node lists are a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! These tips are so helpful to me <3 . @ScottMarcus

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, when you [look at the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) for the methods that we are talking about, you can see that it will state that a live node list is returned. Then, it's just up to you to know and understand what that really means.